# Zsh + RVM gemset and ruby-version not set automatically to .ruby-gemset & .ruby-version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, zsh

Case 1: When i open console direct in project directory (Using Linux Mint)
I have created .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset in my rails project but it doesn't work. It do not set my ruby version and gemset automatically.

Case 2: It do works when i do..

```
$ cd . 
or
$ cd /path/to/project
```

why is this so?

my ~/.zshrc:

```
export PATH="/home/asad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/home/asad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/bin:/home/asad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin:/home/asad/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:$PATH"
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Comment: I have the same problem (I use bash & Konsole). If I 'cd' in a project folder everything works OK. But if I open the Konsole directly in that project's directory it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a .rvmrc file in your home or project directory? That would take priority over .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset, as shown in the rvm docs: https://rvm.io/workflow/projects